# How to extract data from a sql schema file?

Tags: mysql, export-to-csv

I have a exported sql schema file. (similar to what we have here https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_O5AEB2HE08PYEPTGCFLZU9YCV.html)

This file is having all Create table and insert values commands.

I want to export all the database to a CSV or JSON format.

Is there a way to achieve the same?

Comment: You are going to have to make a clearer description of what you are asking

Comment: Do you have a loaded database or just a file generated by an EXPORT?

Comment: I have a explored sql file

Comment: Explored? You mean EXPORTED right

Comment: So import the backup back into a basebase and then write some code to export it in whichever format you want

Comment: Yes, so basically i need the data in csv format for https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_O5AEB2HE08PYEPTGCFLZU9YCV.html script

Comment: *I have a exported sql schema file. (similar to what we have here* This is OracleDB, not MySQL.

Comment: _export all the database_ - does that mean definitions _and_ data?

Comment: *I want to export all the database to a CSV or JSON format.* There is no standard CSV or JSON format which stores complete database dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be asking how to convert the data from the .sql script directly to a raw data format. That would require a SQL parser capable of reading the .sql script format. This is implemented in MySQL using a combination of the `mysql` client and the MySQL Server SQL parser. It would be an awful lot of work to duplicate this.

Honestly, the easiest solution is to use the `mysql` client to import the .sql script's tables and data into a MySQL instance. Then you could dump the data in CSV format, or whatever other format you want.

You can run queries using the `mysql` client in batch mode to dump results to CSV format (really tab-delimited), or you could write a simple client in Python or whatever your favorite language is.

Another alternative is to use `mysqldump --tab` to dump CSV files. I'll encourage you read the documentation about that.